# An error invoked when trying to enter "Virtual Switch Manager"

Tags: hyper-v

When trying to click on: Hyper-V Manager->Actions->Virtual Switch Manager...

I'm getting this error:

> An error occurred while trying to retrieve a list of virtual switches.
>   The operation on computer '***' failed: Generic failure.

This is also avoiding me from creating a Virtual Machine.

as I understand this problem is related to my Network Adapters, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: have you ever found a solution ot this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.